# Why ListView background can not refresh?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, refresh

I want change the ListView's item background dynamicly, so I using the Timer as the event trigger. But after the timer is triggered, the background color can not refresh automatically until I resize the window. Here is my code snippet:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Object> People = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            People.Add(new Person());
        listView.ItemsSource = People;

        System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(theObjectDroped);
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void theObjectDroped(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<int, Brush>(ModifyListViewBackground), i, Brushes.Red);
        }
    }

    private void ModifyListViewBackground(int i, Brush brush)
    {
        listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            ListViewItem row = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;
            if (row != null && row.Background != brush)
            {
                row.Background = brush;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are setting up a event handler for the StatusChanged event:

```
    listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (s, e) =>
```

This gets fired when you do something like change the size of the window, which is why you only see the background colour change when you do something like resize the window.

To make it work as soon as the timer event gets fired, just remove the event handler in your `ModifyListViewBackground` method:

```
    private void ModifyListViewBackground(int i, Brush brush)
    {
        ListViewItem row = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;
        if (row != null && row.Background != brush)
        {
            row.Background = brush;
        }
    }
```

N.B. your timer is set up to trigger after 10ms. This is very fast, when trying this it was almost instantaneous. I set it to 1s (1000ms) so as I could see the event triggering after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing you `ModifyListViewBackground` method - you attach eventhandler and change background only after it is executed.

Do you trigger `listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` somewhere else in your code? If not, this may be most probable case. Also keep in mind that eventhandlers can be stacked many times so each time your timer is triggered you need to clean(deattach) old eventhandlers.

Try to test one of the following versions of `ModifyListViewBackground`. Please note they are more schematic as I don't have IDE at the moment - deattach previous eventhandler, attach new and fire event:

```
private void ModifyListViewBackground(int i, Brush brush)  
    {  
        listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -=StatusChangedCompleted;
        listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged +=StatusChangedCompleted;
        listView.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged();
    }
private void StatusChangedCompleted(object source, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem row = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;  
    if (row != null && row.Background != brush)  
    {  
        row.Background = brush;  
    }  
}
```

Or if event handler isn't requirement this also should work:

```
private void ModifyListViewBackground(int i, Brush brush)  
    {  
        ListViewItem row = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListViewItem;  
            if (row != null && row.Background != brush)  
            {  
                row.Background = brush;  
            }    
    }
```